# Call number in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am a student learning Swift and am having trouble calling a number from a button call. I researched and found this code below in a couple of different places but there is always an error saying "This app is not allowed to query for scheme tel". Is there something in the Info.plist file that I'm missing for this code to work? Or is there another issue?

```
@IBAction func call(_ sender: Any) {
    let number = URL(string: "tel://" + restaurant.number)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(number!) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(number!)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(number!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, seems you're trying to access a url starting with tel:// which your application is denied access.  If you do have access to that domain, access it via your credentials.